# If operator inside for loop

Tags: for-loop, awk, bioinformatics

I have input file as below, need to do this conversion `col1*0 + col2*1 + col3*2` for every 3 column triplet.

**input.txt** - All positive numbers, can be decimals, real file has 1000s of columns.

```
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 0 0
```

I have the below gawk line that does that:

```
gawk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=3)x=(x?x FS:"")(($(i+1))+($(i+2)*2));print x;x=y}' input.txt
0 0
1 2
2 0
```

Additionally, I need to check if 3 numbers are all zeros, if they are all zeros then the conversion should be `-9`.

Pseudo code:

```
if($i==0 & $(i+1)==0 & $(i+2)==0) {-9} else {$(i+1)+$(i+2)*2}
#or as all numbers are positive.
if(($i+$(i+1)+$(i+2))==0) {-9} else {$(i+1)+$(i+2)*2}
```

Expected output:

```
-9 0
1 2
2 -9
```

**Data description:**
This data is output from [IMPUTE2](https://mathgen.stats.ox.ac.uk/impute/impute_v2.html) software -  a genotype imputation and haplotype phasing program. Rows are [SNP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-nucleotide_polymorphism)s, columns are samples. Every SNP is represented by 3 columns. 3 numbers per SNP with range 0-1 (probability of allele AA AB BB). So in above example we have 3 SNPs and 2 samples. Imputation can also be represented as dosage value, 1 number per SNP with range 0-2. We are trying to covert probability format into dosage format. When IMPUTE2 can't give any probabilities to any of the alleles, it outputs as `0 0 0`, then we should convert as no call `-9`.

Comment: So if you're just multiplying by zero, then it's safe to ignore columns 1 and 4, right?

Comment: @ghoti Yes, I am ignoring them in my existing gawk solution, too. `$(i+1))+($(i+2)*2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the sum to be different if the three given columns are `0`. For this, you can expand the ternary operator to something like>

```
gawk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=3) {
          x=$(i+1) + $(i+2)*2;   # the sum
          res=res (res ? FS : "") ($i==0 && $(i+1)==0 && $(i+2)==0 ?-9:x)
        }
       print res; res=""         # print stored line and empty for next loop
      }' file
```

That is, append the value `-9` if all the elements are `0`. Otherwise, the calculated `x`:

```
res=res (res ? FS : "") ($i==0 && $(i+1)==0 && $(i+2)==0 ?-9:x)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^
                           if three columns are 0..........|
```

If all values are positive, the check can be reformatted to just compare if the sum is `0` or not.

```
($i + $(i+1) + $(i+2)) ? x : -9
```

Testing with your file apparently works:

```
$ gawk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=3) {x=$(i+1) + $(i+2)*2; res=res (res ? FS : "") ($i==0 && $(i+1)==0 && $(i+2)==0 ?-9:x)} print res; res=""}' file
-9 0
1 2
2 -9
```

Comment: Could you add more detail on 3rd line? What does `?` mean?

Comment: @zx8754 `var = condition ? "if true" : "if false"` is a ternary operator. For example you can say `x= (var>0) ? var : -var` to make `x` contain `var` without a sign.

Comment: Thank you, will converting `$i==0 && $(i+1)==0 && $(i+2)==0` to `$($i+$(i+1)+$(i+2))==0` make it more efficient? (take the sum and check if it is 0).

Comment: @zx8754 In case of all positive numbers yes, but what if `$i == 1`, `$(i+1) == 0` and `$(i+2) == -1`? The sum is 0 whereas two are not.

Comment: Yes, I understand. My data is all positives, I updated my post. Sorry, should have described my data better from the start.

Comment: @zx8754 no problem! Just updated my answer with this taken into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

another `awk` one-liner (assuming non-negative input values)

```
$ awk '{c1=$2+2*$3;c2=$5+2*$6; print c1||$1?c1:-9,c2||$4?c2:-9}' lop
-9 0
1 2
2 -9
```

Comment: I didn't test it yet, will this work if the number of columns in real data is in 1000s?

Comment: Also, don't rely on the assumption that `c1||$1` equaling zero means that $1,$2,$3 are all zero. For example, $2==2 and $3==-1 means the result is legitimately zero.

Comment: Yes, the zero test is for zero or other.  Computed value uses two fields and "or"ing with the unused field will indicate if all fields are zero or any nonzero.  Assumes the data is non-negative values, I thought it was specified but not sure anymore.

Comment: Non-negative is edited out from the spec!  It won't be correct if you can have negative values since they may cancel each other.

Comment: File is only positive numbers, and will this work when we have 1000s of columns?

Comment: This is not a loop construct only set up for the initial 6 columns.  The logic will work for non negative values only.